# Добавление текста в SVG формат

Tags: html, css, css3, svg

Как в исходник (см. ниже) `SVG` формата добавить текст, чтобы можно было  придать оформление в качестве `CSS` стилей: центровка, выравнивание по вертикали, цвет, размер шрифта и т.д и т.п. (без иллюстратора и каких либо графических редакторов)?

[ссылка](https://codepen.io/assylzhan91/pen/vqaNeB).

```html
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="105" height="105" viewBox="0 0 105 105">
      <defs>
        <style>
          .a {
            fill: aqua;
          }
        </style>
      </defs>
      <title>Artboard 1map</title>
      <path class="a" d="M9.53,3.07l.11.44,1.22,1.23,1.17,0,2.22.85,1.27-.2L17.43,4l.74-.13,1.17.06.45.49h1.09l.74-.56L23,4.32,24.31,6l.43,3.08,1.14.53-.75,2,.32.44.76-.43,2.16.49.39-.41.08-1.14.51-.65,1.17,0,1-1,1.43-.6.35.14,1-.31.35,1.32,3.23.61.55-.61,1.4-.08.37-.9,1.39-1,1,0,1.85-.88,1.35-1.82,1-.33.79.08.92.77,1.71.43,1.56,1.59.57,0,.45,1.16.65.05.78,1.3,1.13-.38,2,1.3,1.08-.19,1.58-1.16,1.21.19L62.73,11l.07.65-.47,1.06-.9.44-.6.89,0,1.45-.4,1,.56.92,1.3-.23,1.85,1.1.58-.14.88.29,1.21-.73,0-.84-.6.44-.62-.27-.4-1.27,1.57.16-.52-1.37.78-.87,1.19-.57,1.85.38,1.79-.45.86-.57,1.27.37,1.67-.73,1.21.33L77.33,14l1.66.27,1.42-.51,1.08.18,1.44-.41,1.76,0L85.76,13h0l.74,2.16,1.61.07.45-.1,1.11-1.33L89.52,13l.5-.29.75.15-.19,2.49-.73.41-.18.46.06,1.8-1.59,1.65.06.37.68.5-.07.59.49.3.26.62,1.93,1.42,2.07,1,1.21-.31.44.37,1.41-.26.41.22L98,26.41l-.29,1,.24.58,1.68,1.36,1.08.05.71.38.2.61-.2.86,1.43-.2,1.33,1.42.64.13L105,33h0l-.48.57-3.38,1.69.57.84-.72.86-.38,1.77.31.39.94.27.54.76-.22.87-1.3.38L98.14,43l-1.57-.19-.75.36L94.3,45l-.2,1.09-.87.24-1.18,1.08.38.88-1,.92-.78,1.43.43.85-.51.52.54.53-2.64,1.57.2.81-.26.64-.8-1.33,0-.43-.95-1.14-.89-.41,0-.73-1.2.25-2-.31-.51.45-1.05-.4-.59.8h-.58l-1.61,2.17.62.66.71.2-.53.44.47.77-.68.72.5,1.81-1.92,1.12-1.41,2.33-.65-.35-.48.21-.62-.17L73.19,63l-2.58.25.63.55-.75,1.44,1,.58.17.39L71,67.33l.09.83-.46,1.72.28.89-.6,1.39-1.92-.39L67,72.32l-.54.69-.92,0-.87.82-.79,1.72.71.56.77.14.32.69.67.1,0,.62.38.22-1.39.43-1,1.87-.58.31L63,80.46l-1.28.77.05.83-.75,1.28.17,2.6,2.48,1.43L65,89.24l-.14,1-.53.29,0,.93.74.39.15.8-.6.83-1.23.43L63,95.66l-.34.37,1.68,1.48,1,2.58-.14,1.8.54,2.61-.45.39-1.36.15h0l-1.32-.28-.53.23-.53-.34h0l-.08-2-1.15-1.56L60,99.6,58.84,99,57.45,97.2,56,97.31l0-.67-.44-.55v-.92l-.32-.42-1.19.17-.76-.56-1,.27-.46-.57-1.53-.3-.42-1.05.42-.86L50,91.32l.34-1-2-.45-.69-.93,2.2-3.09L49,84.62,46.6,83.1l-.47-.75L46.67,80l.79-1.57-.55-1.26-1.53-.86-.3-1,.13-.89-.74-2.3L44,71.66l-.42-2.54.56-1.53,0-1.33-1.71-3-.77-.46-.34.14-1.6-1.25-1.13-3.81L38,57l-.39-1.37-1.28-1.38.17-1.45.34-.38-1.27-.25-1,.88-.81,0-.19-.13.15-.48-.91-.05-.18-.61-.73-.13-.25-.41-1.6.3-.77-.46-.45.14,0-.8-.76,0-.08-2.24-.62-.42.36-.18.43-1.17L27,44.84l0-1.71-1-.79,1-.29.27-.39,1.07.79.32-.17-.52-2.42.17-1.41-1.11-.68L27,38l.12-.61-.38-.1L25.66,36h-.33l-.91.77-.33-.2L24,35.84l-1.07-.23-.72.22-1.09-1-1.07-2-.84-.77-.06-.75-.41-.51,1-1.39,0-.41L18.29,27.5l-.49-1.11-.07-1.3-1.19-.38-2.34.23-.8.52-1-.5-2.66.38-.82-1.16-1.12-.45L7.61,23,6,22.87H5.51L4.38,22l-1.87-.11-.22-1.41-.87-.58h0L.93,18.52l-.43-3L1.59,14.3l.34-.8-1.3-3,.05-.64.38-.32-.27-.9L.86,7,3,5.07l.35-.14.43.48L4,4.79l-.5-.67-.7.06-.67-.53,0-1.21,1.24-.95L4,.64,5.28.19l.45.86.88.61,2.3.71Z"/>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для стилизации и позиционирования текста SVG есть очень много атрибутов.
Многие совпадают с атрибутами css, такие как `fill`, `stroke`, `stroke-width`, `font-sise`, `font-weight`, `font-family`

**1.  Позиционирование текста с помощью атрибута text-anchor**

```html
 <svg  xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 200" height="200" width="200" style="border:1px solid red;">
 
 <line x1="100" y1="5" x2="100" y2="195" stroke="dodgerblue" />
 <g fill="black" font-family="Verdana, serif" font-size="24" font-weight="900">
 
 <text x="100" y="60"  style="text-anchor: start;"> Start </text>
<text x="100" y="110" style="text-anchor: Middle;">  middle </text>
<text x="100" y="160"  style="text-anchor: end;">  End </text>    
 </g>
 
 </svg>
```

**2. dominant-baseline**

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M20,20 L180,20 M20,50 L180,50 M20,80 L180,80" stroke="grey" />
    
    <text dominant-baseline="baseline" x="30" y="20">Baseline</text>
    <text dominant-baseline="middle" x="30" y="50">Middle</text>
    <text dominant-baseline="hanging" x="30" y="80">Hanging</text>
</svg>
```

**3.  позиционирование строк многострочного текста с помощью `tspan`**

В svg нет автоматического переноса текста, как в Html поэтому приходится применять относительное позиционирование строк **многострочного текста** с помощью тегов `<tspan> .. </tspan>`, которые имеют атрибуты `x` `y` для абсолютного позиционирования текста и  `dx` и `dy` для относительного смещения текста одной строки относительно другой по координатам.

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      viewBox="0 300 794 1123"style="border:1px solid gray;">  


  <g id="g10">
   
  <text x="200" y="360"  fill="black" font-family="Verdana, serif" font-size="24" font-weight="900"> Заголовок 10</text> 
  
    <path id="path12" d="M491 389H66v226h425z" style="fill:#fff;stroke:#231f20"/> 
 <text x="80" y="410" fill="grey" font-size="18" font-weight="900"> Текст 10
 <tspan dx="10">Текст 10 </tspan>
 <tspan dx="10">Текст 10 </tspan>
 <tspan dx="10">Текст 10 </tspan>
 <tspan dx="10">Текст 10 </tspan>
 <tspan dx="-400" dy="20">Текст 10 </tspan>
 </text>
  </g> 
  
  <g id="g11">
    
  
    <path id="path14" d="M253 470H72v138h181z" style="fill:#fff;stroke:#231f20"/>
  <text x="90" y="490"  fill="black" font-family="Verdana, serif" font-size="18" font-weight="900"> Заголовок 11</text> 
  
  <text x="80" y="520" fill="grey" font-size="18" font-weight="300"> Текст 11 Текст 11 
 <tspan dx="-130" dy="20">Текст 11 </tspan>
 <tspan dx="0">Текст 11 </tspan>
</text>
  </g>
  <g id="g12">
   
    <path id="path16" d="M482 470H261V608H482Z" style="fill:#fff;stroke:#231f20"/>
 
  <text x="300" y="490"  fill="black" font-family="Verdana, serif" font-size="18" font-weight="900"> Заголовок 12</text> 
  
   <text x="300" y="520" fill="grey" font-size="18" font-weight="300"> Текст 12 Текст 12 
 <tspan dx="-130" dy="20">Текст 12 </tspan>
 <tspan dx="0">Текст 12 </tspan>  
 
 </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4):

В `svg` для отображения текста тег `<text>`, только поместить его надо под фигурой, т.к. элементы `svg` отображаются в том порядке, в котором они идут в разметке:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  height="100vh" viewBox="0 0 105 105">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .a {
        fill: aqua;
      }
      text {
        text-anchor: middle;
        alignment-baseline: middle;
        fill:red;
        stroke:black;
        stroke-width:0.4;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
 
  <path class="a" d="M9.53,3.07l.11.44,1.22,1.23,1.17,0,2.22.85,1.27-.2L17.43,4l.74-.13,1.17.06.45.49h1.09l.74-.56L23,4.32,24.31,6l.43,3.08,1.14.53-.75,2,.32.44.76-.43,2.16.49.39-.41.08-1.14.51-.65,1.17,0,1-1,1.43-.6.35.14,1-.31.35,1.32,3.23.61.55-.61,1.4-.08.37-.9,1.39-1,1,0,1.85-.88,1.35-1.82,1-.33.79.08.92.77,1.71.43,1.56,1.59.57,0,.45,1.16.65.05.78,1.3,1.13-.38,2,1.3,1.08-.19,1.58-1.16,1.21.19L62.73,11l.07.65-.47,1.06-.9.44-.6.89,0,1.45-.4,1,.56.92,1.3-.23,1.85,1.1.58-.14.88.29,1.21-.73,0-.84-.6.44-.62-.27-.4-1.27,1.57.16-.52-1.37.78-.87,1.19-.57,1.85.38,1.79-.45.86-.57,1.27.37,1.67-.73,1.21.33L77.33,14l1.66.27,1.42-.51,1.08.18,1.44-.41,1.76,0L85.76,13h0l.74,2.16,1.61.07.45-.1,1.11-1.33L89.52,13l.5-.29.75.15-.19,2.49-.73.41-.18.46.06,1.8-1.59,1.65.06.37.68.5-.07.59.49.3.26.62,1.93,1.42,2.07,1,1.21-.31.44.37,1.41-.26.41.22L98,26.41l-.29,1,.24.58,1.68,1.36,1.08.05.71.38.2.61-.2.86,1.43-.2,1.33,1.42.64.13L105,33h0l-.48.57-3.38,1.69.57.84-.72.86-.38,1.77.31.39.94.27.54.76-.22.87-1.3.38L98.14,43l-1.57-.19-.75.36L94.3,45l-.2,1.09-.87.24-1.18,1.08.38.88-1,.92-.78,1.43.43.85-.51.52.54.53-2.64,1.57.2.81-.26.64-.8-1.33,0-.43-.95-1.14-.89-.41,0-.73-1.2.25-2-.31-.51.45-1.05-.4-.59.8h-.58l-1.61,2.17.62.66.71.2-.53.44.47.77-.68.72.5,1.81-1.92,1.12-1.41,2.33-.65-.35-.48.21-.62-.17L73.19,63l-2.58.25.63.55-.75,1.44,1,.58.17.39L71,67.33l.09.83-.46,1.72.28.89-.6,1.39-1.92-.39L67,72.32l-.54.69-.92,0-.87.82-.79,1.72.71.56.77.14.32.69.67.1,0,.62.38.22-1.39.43-1,1.87-.58.31L63,80.46l-1.28.77.05.83-.75,1.28.17,2.6,2.48,1.43L65,89.24l-.14,1-.53.29,0,.93.74.39.15.8-.6.83-1.23.43L63,95.66l-.34.37,1.68,1.48,1,2.58-.14,1.8.54,2.61-.45.39-1.36.15h0l-1.32-.28-.53.23-.53-.34h0l-.08-2-1.15-1.56L60,99.6,58.84,99,57.45,97.2,56,97.31l0-.67-.44-.55v-.92l-.32-.42-1.19.17-.76-.56-1,.27-.46-.57-1.53-.3-.42-1.05.42-.86L50,91.32l.34-1-2-.45-.69-.93,2.2-3.09L49,84.62,46.6,83.1l-.47-.75L46.67,80l.79-1.57-.55-1.26-1.53-.86-.3-1,.13-.89-.74-2.3L44,71.66l-.42-2.54.56-1.53,0-1.33-1.71-3-.77-.46-.34.14-1.6-1.25-1.13-3.81L38,57l-.39-1.37-1.28-1.38.17-1.45.34-.38-1.27-.25-1,.88-.81,0-.19-.13.15-.48-.91-.05-.18-.61-.73-.13-.25-.41-1.6.3-.77-.46-.45.14,0-.8-.76,0-.08-2.24-.62-.42.36-.18.43-1.17L27,44.84l0-1.71-1-.79,1-.29.27-.39,1.07.79.32-.17-.52-2.42.17-1.41-1.11-.68L27,38l.12-.61-.38-.1L25.66,36h-.33l-.91.77-.33-.2L24,35.84l-1.07-.23-.72.22-1.09-1-1.07-2-.84-.77-.06-.75-.41-.51,1-1.39,0-.41L18.29,27.5l-.49-1.11-.07-1.3-1.19-.38-2.34.23-.8.52-1-.5-2.66.38-.82-1.16-1.12-.45L7.61,23,6,22.87H5.51L4.38,22l-1.87-.11-.22-1.41-.87-.58h0L.93,18.52l-.43-3L1.59,14.3l.34-.8-1.3-3,.05-.64.38-.32-.27-.9L.86,7,3,5.07l.35-.14.43.48L4,4.79l-.5-.67-.7.06-.67-.53,0-1.21,1.24-.95L4,.64,5.28.19l.45.86.88.61,2.3.71Z"/>
  
  <text x="50" y="50">Artboard 1map</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Здравствуйте! Скажите пожалуйста, а если внутри svg окажется несколько path элементов  и для каждого из них нужно будет сделать отдельный текст, полагаю надо для каждого path сделать идентификатор и только потом, задавать   <text x="50" y="50" id="somId">Artboard 1map</text>??
Только сейчас пришло в голову про это

Comment: @John да, можно их добавить потом программно, а `cx` и `cy` посчитать через `path.getBBox()`

Comment: @StrangerintheQ что такое в этом случае `х` ? http://jsfiddle.net/longsonr/pGBuj/

Comment: @MaximLensky левая верхняя координата, обрамляющего прямоугольника

Comment: @Stranger in the Q   `левая верхняя координата, обрамляющего прямоугольника` это справедливо для всех базовых фигур svg, но для текста это наоборот **нижняя левая координата первого символа слова** Попробуй сделать Y="0" и текста не увидишь. Он будет выше холста. Правда, если добавишь атрибуты  `dominant-baseline="hanging"` то только тогда увидишь текст при y="0"

Comment: @Alexandr_TT ок, только в примере Максима это все же `path`

Comment: @Alexandr_TT https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/rErpoB

Comment: @John задание Идентификаторов для текста никак не связано с позиционированием `path` или текста. ID или классы для текста, скорее нужны для стилизации самого текста, хотя стили можно задавать любым способом, хоть внутри svg, хоть из внешней таблицы, хоть с помощю атрибутов представления. см. ниже ответы

Answer (score 2):

Когда объект достаточно большой и имеет много мелких деталей, то лучше наносить текстовую информацию не на карту например, а выводить в виде подсказок.

Для вывода текста в подсказке при наведении на svg элемент есть тег `<title>`

Чтобы подсказка заработала, необходимо обернуть svg элемент в групповой тег `<g>`

```
<g>
 <title> Подсказка информация </title>
<path> ......</path>
</g>
```

Ниже для примера приведена карта Казахстана.
Для вывода подсказки дождитесь конца анимации прорисовки карты и наведите курсор на окружность обозначающую место положение столицы Казахстана или на саму карту Казахстана, подсказки будут разные.

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<svg width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 120 120"  >
<g> 
<!-- Вывод подсказки -->
<title>
Столица Нур-Султан
Крупнейшие города Алма-Ата, Нур-Султан, Шымкент, Караганда, Актобе, Тараз, Павлодар, Усть-Каменогорск 
Население  • Оценка (2019) 18 395 660[6] чел. 
Территория 9-я в мире
 • Всего 2 724 902[4] км²
</title>
<path id="KZ" title="Kazakhstan" class="land" transform="translate(-603 -260)" fill="none" stroke="grey" stroke-width="0.2" stroke-dasharray="395" stroke-dashoffset="395" d="M674.22,333.11L672.61,333.81L668.92,336.42L667.69,339.07L666.64,339.09L665.88,337.34L662.31,337.22L661.74,334.16L660.37,334.13L660.58,330.33L657.23,327.53L652.42,327.83L649.13,328.39L646.45,324.89L644.16,323.41L639.81,320.57L639.29,320.22L632.07,322.57L632.18,336.7L630.74,336.88L628.78,333.95L626.88,332.89L623.7,333.68L622.46,334.93L622.3,334.01L622.99,332.44L622.46,331.12L619.21,329.82L617.94,326.35L616.4,325.37L616.3,324.09L619.03,324.46L619.14,321.58L621.52,320.94L623.97,321.53L624.48,317.62L623.98,315.11L621.17,315.31L618.79,314.31L615.54,316.1L612.93,316.96L611.5,316.3L611.79,314.2L610,311.44L607.92,311.55L605.54,308.72L607.16,305.5L606.34,304.63L608.57,299.86L611.46,302.39L611.81,299.2L617.59,294.35L621.97,294.23L628.16,297.33L631.47,299.12L634.45,297.25L638.89,297.17L642.48,299.46L643.3,298.15L647.23,298.34L647.94,296.23L643.39,293.14L646.08,290.91L645.56,289.66L648.25,288.45L646.23,285.25L647.51,283.63L658,281.97L659.37,280.78L666.39,278.99L668.91,276.95L673.95,278.01L674.83,283.02L677.76,281.86L681.36,283.49L681.13,286.07L683.82,285.8L690.84,281.31L689.82,282.81L693.4,286.47L699.66,298.05L701.16,295.72L705.02,298.28L709.05,297.14L710.59,297.94L711.94,300.49L713.9,301.33L715.1,303.18L718.71,302.6L720.2,305.23L718.06,308.06L715.73,308.46L715.6,312.64L714.04,314.5L708.48,313.15L706.46,320.41L705.02,321.3L699.47,322.88L701.99,329.63L700.07,330.63L700.29,332.79L698.56,332.24L697.16,330.87L693,330.47L688.35,330.37L687.33,330.79L683.33,329.18L681.74,329.98L681.31,332.22L676.69,330.91L674.85,331.45z">
 <animate id="dash" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" dur="4s" fill="freeze" values="395;0"/> 
<animate id="fillPath" attributeName="fill" values="white;#AFCD72" begin="dash.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze" />
</path>  
</g>
<text x="40" y="50"  font-size="12"  fill="none" stroke="none" >Казахстан 
     <animate id="fillKaz" dur="1.5s" begin="fillPath.end"  repeatCount="1"
        attributeName="fill"   values="#AFCD72;#787A78" fill="freeze" />
 </text>

<g  opacity="0"> 
<!-- Вывод подсказки -->
 <title>
  Семипалатинск (Алаш-Кала) (13 декабря 1917 — 5 марта 1920)
  Оренбург (10 июля 1919 — 5 апреля 1925)
  Кызыл-Орда (6 апреля 1925 — 2 апреля 1927)
  Алма-Ата (3 апреля 1927 — 27 декабря 1993)
  Алматы (28 декабря 1993 — 9 декабря 1997)
  Акмола (10 декабря 1997 — 5 мая 1998)
  Астана (6 мая 1998 — 22 марта 2019)
  Нур-Султан (23 марта 2019 — настоящее время)
 </title>
<circle cx="68" cy="35" r="2" fill="#787A78" stroke="none"  />
<circle cx="68" cy="35" r="0.8" fill="#787A78" stroke="white" stroke-width="0.5" />
<animate id="fillCircle" attributeName="opacity" values="0;1" begin="fillKaz.end" dur="0.8s" fill="freeze" />
</g>
 <g> 
 
 <text x="70" y="32" font-size="5"  fill="none" stroke="none"   >Нур-Султан (Астана) 
  <animate id="fillAstana" dur="1.5s" begin="fillCircle.end"  repeatCount="1"
        attributeName="fill"   values="#AFCD72;#787A78" fill="freeze" />
 </text>
</g>
</svg>
```

Данные взяты из [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD)